# Is there no way to create a delay in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Basically I have a `3000.txt` file that I am removing all vowels from, except if it doesn't contain consonants. The new words are appended to a new `TMP.txt` file.
However, some words are missing entirely, and other words are missing a few consonants. I suspect this is due to the script appending to the file too quickly.
Therefore I want to insert a delay of maybe 20 ms or whatever suits. It's just a homegamer script, I don't care if it's efficient.

```
var fs = require("fs");
var words = fs.readFileSync("3000.txt").toString();
words = words.split("\n");

var vowels = /[aeiouy]/;
var consonants = /[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvxz]/;
var TMPword = "";

for(var testword of words) 
{
    if(testword.match(vowels))
    {
        if(testword.match(consonants))
        {
            TMPword = testword.replace(/a|e|i|o|u|y/g,'')
            fs.appendFile("TMP.txt", TMPword, function (err, file) {if(err) throw err;} );
        }
        continue;
    }

    //Delay goes here//
}
```

Comment: Why not just use `appendFileSync` instead of `appendFile`?

Comment: NodeJS is single threaded. A delay would delay all further operations.

Comment: Sorry, I did tag it as java and a couple other things, but I guess it got autocorrected. I changed the java tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if a delay would work, but I notice that you use appendFile in a loop, maybe you should use string instead, and call appendFile once when it's done.
Otherwise, I suggest that use appendFileSync or await appendFile.
Sorry, here's my code example.

```
var fs = require("fs");
var words = fs.readFileSync("3000.txt").toString();
words = words.split("\n");

var vowels = /[aeiouy]/;
var consonants = /[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvxz]/;
var TMPword = "";

let str = '';

for(var testword of words) 
{
    if(testword.match(vowels))
    {
        if(testword.match(consonants))
        {
            TMPword = testword.replace(/a|e|i|o|u|y/g,'')
            str += TMPword;
        }
        continue;
    }

    //Delay goes here//
}
fs.appendFile("TMP.txt", str, function (err, file) {if(err) throw err;} );
```

or

```
fs.appendFileSync("TMP.txt", TMPword);
```

or

```
await fs.appendFile("TMP.txt", TMPword, function (err, file) {if(err) throw err;} ); // function must be with async
```

Comment: The appendFileSync fixed my problem entirely. I guess I missed that entry on the webpage I was looking at :)

Comment: this answer would be better if you posted a code example of your solution.

Comment: I litterally just added the word "sync" to "appendFile" = "appendFileSync"

Comment: you also suggest "or await appendFile" but if it's that easy ok.

Answer (score 2):

You need to wait until the `appendFile` callback is called before proceeding with the next call. There are several ways to do that, but this asynchronous loop should do the trick:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var words = fs.readFileSync("3000.txt").toString();
words = words.split("\n");

var vowels = /[aeiouy]/;
var consonants = /[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvxz]/;

function loop(words) {
    if (!words.length) return; // All done
    var word = words.shift().replace(/a|e|i|o|u|y/g, '');
    fs.appendFile("TMP.txt", word, function (err, file) {
        if(err) throw err;
        loop(words); // Only process next after completing this one
    });
}
// Only retain words that pass the conditions:
words = words.filter(testword => testword.match(vowels) && testword.match(consonants));
// Start asynchronous loop
loop(words);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe setTimeout could help you here?

```
setTimeout(function(){ console.log('foo'); }, 3000);
```

1000 ms = 1 second;

Or ES6 syntax

```
setTimeout( ()=> console.log('foo'), 3000 )
```

Comment: why would you use `alert` in node on the server side?

Comment: But still it's node, so it would be better to do `console.log('foo')` if you're going to give a working example, as alert will raise an error in node.